# Video Player multiple Raspberrys via WIFI

Tags: raspbian, streaming-video

Is it possible to get lets say 5-10 Raspberrys to play the same Video on a TV via hdmi and the should get the videos from a folder located on a server in the Wifi?

They dont have to be in sync. I have a Fitness Studio with multiple Screens and want a cheap solution to get the same images to all screens and change the shown videos via ftp or webinterface or something like that.

If there is a nice Webfrontend that would be good to

We have a pi 3 model b for testing here.

Comment: Do the videos need to be played in sync (web streaming) or can they be started independently (simply file shared over NFS)?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JohnHawthorne they dont have to be in sync. I have a Fitness Studio with multiple Screens and want a cheap solution to get the same images to all screens and change the shown videos via ftp or webinterface or something like that

Comment: I've thought about this and there are just too many ways to do this so it would help to have more information about what you need to do.  Otherwise try searching for something like Raspberry PI kiosk mode.

Comment: 5-10 unicast video streams over one wifi? I don't believe that this will work. Maybe multicast can help but then you cannot simply use a folder on a server.